# Import jQuery Plugin with JSPM

Tags: jquery, plugins, shim, jspm

I'm trying to import the jQuery plugin [jQuery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/) with JSPM.

So far I installed it with

```
jspm install npm:jquery.scrollto
```

and now I'm trying to import it with

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import scrollTo from 'jquery.scrollto';
```

Now I'm only getting

```
$(...).scrollTo is not a function
```

errors.

I tried to shim it, but I never did it before and can't find a good explanation how to do it, if it is necessary. Can you help me or show me a good explanation when and how do I need to shim things?

Comment: i tried minutes ago in a brand new project. `jspm install jquery`, `jspm install npm:jquery.scrollto`, then importing like you did and worked without any further action on my side. Still having this issue?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still having the problem. If you bundle your app with `jspm bundle-sfx app/main app.js` does it still work? Can you show me a fiddle or a small repo of your project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tested on a clean project and here are the steps that i followed:

1. `jspm install jquery`
2. `jspm install npm:jquery.scrollto -o "{format: 'global'}"` - (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29267477/1446845))
3. add the imports in my `app.js` as described in the question.
4. tested both from dev mode and from a self executing bundle with no errors.

You can clone a test repo I've put up [here on Github](https://github.com/nobitagit/jq-jspm), the steps to build are in the readme. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. I think the override you did in step 2 did it.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me debug including my own jQuery plugin via jspm. Now I can at least tell others how to do it.